# QT QOverload was not declared in this scope on Travis CI

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, github, travis-ci

So I'm currently trying to setup Travis CI for a Qt project on GitHub however I'm getting an error on compiling. It works perfectly fine on my (windows) machine however not on the Ubuntu Travis CI build.

The issue I'm getting in particular is

```
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -O2 -std=c++0x -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIE -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_SQL_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I/usr/include/qt5 -I/usr/include/qt5/QtWidgets -I/usr/include/qt5/QtSql -I/usr/include/qt5/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt5/QtCore -I. -I. -o BacklogManager.o BacklogManager/BacklogManager.cpp
BacklogManager/BacklogManager.cpp: In member function ‘void BacklogManager::ConnectActions()’:
BacklogManager/BacklogManager.cpp:267:5: error: ‘QOverload’ was not declared in this scope
     QOverload<const QString&>::of(&QComboBox::currentIndexChanged), this,
     ^
BacklogManager/BacklogManager.cpp:267:15: error: expected primary-expression before ‘const’
     QOverload<const QString&>::of(&QComboBox::currentIndexChanged), this,
```

Again, this works perfectly on my machine. I have included  in BacklogManager.cpp. I'm just not sure why this is not defined in that scope on Travis CI.

.travis.yml

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2017-10-25T12:09:46
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui sql

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = BacklogManager
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += c++11

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which has been marked as deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0


SOURCES += \
    BacklogManager/main.cpp \
    BacklogManager/GeneratedFiles/qrc_BacklogManagerForm.cpp \
    BacklogManager/AboutForm.cpp \
    BacklogManager/BacklogManager.cpp \
    BacklogManager/FilterForm.cpp \
    BacklogManager/GameCollection.cpp \
    BacklogManager/GameForm.cpp \
    BacklogManager/GameStats.cpp \
    BacklogManager/ImportCSV.cpp \
    BacklogManager/SQLDatabase.cpp \
    BacklogManager/TableWidget.cpp \
    BacklogManager/Utilities.cpp

HEADERS += \
    BacklogManager/GeneratedFiles/ui_AboutForm.h \
    BacklogManager/GeneratedFiles/ui_BacklogManagerForm.h \
    BacklogManager/GeneratedFiles/ui_FilterForm.h \
    BacklogManager/GeneratedFiles/ui_GameForm.h \
    BacklogManager/GeneratedFiles/ui_GameStats.h \
    BacklogManager/AboutForm.h \
    BacklogManager/BacklogManager.h \
    BacklogManager/Defines.h \
    BacklogManager/FilterForm.h \
    BacklogManager/GameCollection.h \
    BacklogManager/GameForm.h \
    BacklogManager/GameStats.h \
    BacklogManager/ImportCSV.h \
    BacklogManager/SQLDatabase.h \
    BacklogManager/TableWidget.h \
    BacklogManager/Utilities.h \

FORMS += \
    BacklogManager/FilterForm.ui \
    BacklogManager/BacklogManagerForm.ui \
    BacklogManager/AboutForm.ui \
    BacklogManager/GameForm.ui \
    BacklogManager/GameStats.ui \
    BacklogManager/AddGame.ui
```

(Shortened) Travis CI build log

```
[0K$ git checkout -qf FETCH_HEAD
travis_fold:end:git.checkout
[0K$ export CXX=g++
$ export CC=gcc
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 4.8.4
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

travis_fold:start:before_install.1
[0Ktravis_time:start:0688fd46
[0K$ sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpisgvwm1_/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpisgvwm1_/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key BA9EF27F from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: /tmp/tmpisgvwm1_/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key BA9EF27F: public key "Launchpad Toolchain builds" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
OK

travis_time:end:0688fd46:start=1509290965413243222,finish=1509290967005300406,duration=1592057184
[0Ktravis_fold:end:before_install.1
[0Ktravis_fold:start:before_install.2
[0Ktravis_time:start:0457fc09
[0K$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:beineri/opt-qt592-trusty -y
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpx6oia2wd/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpx6oia2wd/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key E9977759 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: /tmp/tmpx6oia2wd/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key E9977759: public key "Launchpad PPA for Stephan Binner" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
OK

travis_time:end:0457fc09:start=1509290967009916994,finish=1509290968526560850,duration=1516643856
[0Ktravis_fold:end:before_install.2
[0Ktravis_fold:start:before_install.3
[0Ktravis_time:start:292ac127
[0K$ sudo apt-get update -qq
W: http://dl.hhvm.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease: Signature by key 36AEF64D0207E7EEE352D4875A16E7281BE7A449 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
W: http://ppa.launchpad.net/couchdb/stable/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg: Signature by key 15866BAFD9BCC4F3C1E0DFC7D69548E1C17EAB57 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)

travis_time:end:292ac127:start=1509290968531061520,finish=1509290974280712646,duration=5749651126
[0Ktravis_fold:end:before_install.3
[0Ktravis_fold:start:before_install.4
[0Ktravis_time:start:0fcaba98
[0K$ sudo apt-get -qq install qt5-default qt59base qt59declarative libqt5svg5-dev qttools5-dev qttools5-dev-tools
 update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mir/clientplatform/mesa/ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_mirclientplatform.conf (x86_64-linux-gnu_mirclientplatform_conf) in auto mode
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.13) ...

travis_time:end:0fcaba98:start=1509290974285317621,finish=1509291036193996862,duration=61908679241
[0Ktravis_fold:end:before_install.4
[0Ktravis_fold:start:before_install.5
[0Ktravis_time:start:07c7d119
[0K$ export QMAKE=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmake

travis_time:end:07c7d119:start=1509291036198658415,finish=1509291036202433724,duration=3775309
[0Ktravis_fold:end:before_install.5
[0Ktravis_time:start:09d09b0a
[0K$ qmake

travis_time:end:09d09b0a:start=1509291036207049765,finish=1509291036282556254,duration=75506489
[0K
[32;1mThe command "qmake" exited with 0.[0m
travis_time:start:1c2447c8
[0K$ make
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/uic BacklogManager/FilterForm.ui -o ui_FilterForm.h
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/uic BacklogManager/BacklogManagerForm.ui -o ui_BacklogManagerForm.h
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/uic BacklogManager/AboutForm.ui -o ui_AboutForm.h
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/uic BacklogManager/GameForm.ui -o ui_GameForm.h
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/uic BacklogManager/GameStats.ui -o ui_GameStats.h
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/uic BacklogManager/AddGame.ui -o ui_AddGame.h
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -O2 -std=c++0x -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIE -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_SQL_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I/usr/include/qt5 -I/usr/include/qt5/QtWidgets -I/usr/include/qt5/QtSql -I/usr/include/qt5/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt5/QtCore -I. -I. -o main.o BacklogManager/main.cpp
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -O2 -std=c++0x -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIE -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_SQL_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I/usr/include/qt5 -I/usr/include/qt5/QtWidgets -I/usr/include/qt5/QtSql -I/usr/include/qt5/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt5/QtCore -I. -I. -o qrc_BacklogManagerForm.o BacklogManager/GeneratedFiles/qrc_BacklogManagerForm.cpp
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -O2 -std=c++0x -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIE -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_SQL_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I/usr/include/qt5 -I/usr/include/qt5/QtWidgets -I/usr/include/qt5/QtSql -I/usr/include/qt5/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt5/QtCore -I. -I. -o AboutForm.o BacklogManager/AboutForm.cpp
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -O2 -std=c++0x -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIE -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_SQL_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I/usr/include/qt5 -I/usr/include/qt5/QtWidgets -I/usr/include/qt5/QtSql -I/usr/include/qt5/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt5/QtCore -I. -I. -o BacklogManager.o BacklogManager/BacklogManager.cpp
BacklogManager/BacklogManager.cpp: In member function â€˜void BacklogManager::ConnectActions()â€™:
BacklogManager/BacklogManager.cpp:267:5: error: â€˜QOverloadâ€™ was not declared in this scope
     QOverload<const QString&>::of(&QComboBox::currentIndexChanged), this,
     ^
BacklogManager/BacklogManager.cpp:267:15: error: expected primary-expression before â€˜constâ€™
     QOverload<const QString&>::of(&QComboBox::currentIndexChanged), this,
               ^
make: *** [BacklogManager.o] Error 1

travis_time:end:1c2447c8:start=1509291036287279268,finish=1509291040070812417,duration=3783533149
[0K
[31;1mThe command "make" exited with 2.[0m

Done. Your build exited with 1.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [PPA description](https://launchpad.net/~beineri/+archive/ubuntu/opt-qt592-trusty) of the PPA you use, Qt5.9 will be installed under `/opt/qt59`, yet the travis output shows 
`export QMAKE=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmake`.

It guess this is the path to the Qt version that ships with Ubuntu, which probably is too old to include `QOverload`. Changing that path to `/opt/qt59/bin/qmake` should fix your problem.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. This worked.

To clarify for anyone else looking at this, in the .travis.yml I removed the "export QMAKE" line and change the line "qmake" to "- /opt/qt59/bin/qmake"